# jQuery I can't remove div tags when I paste text

Tags: jquery, clipboard, paste

My code removes all html tags except  .

I need to paste plain text.

My HTM, where I paste the content:

```
<p contenteditable="true">A high altitude hike which offers incredible views of Aconcagua (6958m) and Tupungato (6427m) in Argentina.</p>
```

My jQuery code:

```
$('[contenteditable]').on('paste', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var text = '';

                if (e.clipboardData || e.originalEvent.clipboardData) {
                    text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
                } else if (window.clipboardData) {
                    text = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
                }


                if (document.queryCommandSupported('insertText')) {
                    document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
                } else {
                    document.execCommand('paste', false, text);
                }
            });
```

My jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ovnx27pg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `text.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '');`

```
$('[contenteditable]').on('paste', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var text = '';

    if (e.clipboardData || e.originalEvent.clipboardData) {
        text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    } else if (window.clipboardData) {
        text = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
    }
    text = text.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '');

    if (document.queryCommandSupported('insertText')) {
        document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
    } else {
        document.execCommand('paste', false, text);
    }
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/<div>/gi,'<br>').replace(/<\/div>/gi,''));
});

$('[contenteditable]').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
         document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br><br>');
      return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: When pasting paragraphs with line breaks, insert <div> </div>, paragraphs and line breaks. Can you make it insert <br> in line breaks?

Comment: better if you can provide some example

Comment: I check it only happens in browsers that use Chrome as an engine(ex Opera), in Firefox, when I paste the text insert <br>.

If you use Google Chrome, you can paste paragraphs. When you press the Enter key for line break also enter <div> </div>

https://jsfiddle.net/shgkejyw/

Comment: That solves the line breaks when I press the Enter key.

One more help please.

When I paste simple texts it still adds blank <div> </div> and not <br> to the contenteditable.

Che my example:

https://jsfiddle.net/r7xheLfn/1/

Bug only in Chrome (Firefox good)

Comment: check now i have replaced div with br

Comment: In jsFiddle it works fantastic, but in other projects the code, moves/adds tag </div> needlessly in parents level. I'm seeing why.

Thank you very much for all your help, it has been the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) that wrap `HTML` and return plain text from it.

```
$('[contenteditable]').on('paste', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var text = '';

    if (e.clipboardData || e.originalEvent.clipboardData) {
        text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    } else if (window.clipboardData) {
        text = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
    }
    if (text) {
        text = $(text).text().trim();
    }

    if (document.queryCommandSupported('insertText')) {
        document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
     } else {
        document.execCommand('paste', false, text);
     }
});
```

[jsfiddle()](https://jsfiddle.net/47sgcdym/13/).

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation.